# Assert.AreEqual failed with identical values in C# unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In unit testing `Assert.AreEqual()` fails when even you get "expected answer" is same as "actual answer". I was expecting this double value:

```
-0.562253530231749
```

and I got the same value:

```
-0.562253530231749
```

when I was getting the same answer as expected while unit testing my code .

I encountered an issue in my C# unit test where the `Assert.AreEqual()` statement is failing despite having identical expected and actual values. The error message reads:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected: <-0.562253530231749>. Actual:
> <-0.562253530231749>.

While the values appear to be the same, floating-point arithmetic precision might be causing this unexpected failure. Floating-point numbers can exhibit tiny variations due to how computers represent real numbers. To address this, I attempted to use `Assert.AreEqual()` with a delta (tolerance) value. However, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
double expectedValue = -0.562253530231749;
double actualValue = /* your actual value here */;

double delta = 0.0000000001; // Adjust based on precision requirements

Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, delta);
```

solves this error because it is setting delta precision only upto 10 digits of ur answer hence this problem got solved